# Existence of a weak solution to elliptic PDE with nonsmooth Robin boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, elliptic-equations

Let $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^N$ with a smooth boundary $\partial\Omega$ and consider the elliptic PDE
\begin{alignat*}{4}
   \mbox{D.E.} & \quad{\displaystyle \Delta u -u =0 },&& \quad x\in\Omega\setminus\partial\Omega, \nonumber\\ 
   \mbox{B.C.}& \quad{\displaystyle \frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}+\kappa(x)u=0},&& \quad x\in\partial\Omega,  
   \end{alignat*}
where it is assumed that function $\kappa(x)\in L^p(\partial\Omega)$ is strictly positive on $\partial\Omega$ and is bounded by a positive constant $M$. Is it correct to assume that a solution to this linear problem exists in weak form?

1. Does the weak form representation in
   \begin{equation*}
   -\int_{\Omega}\nabla u \cdot\nabla\phi\,{\mbox d}x -\int_{\partial\Omega}\kappa(x)u\phi\,{\mbox d}s + \int_\Omega u\phi\,{\mbox d}x =0 \quad \forall \phi\in H^1.
   \end{equation*}
   make sense?
2. Am I assuming that the test function belongs to the correct space?
3. Is it possible to obtain a priori estimate for this solution to show that it is bounded?

I am aware that these questions are well established in the case where $\kappa$ is a constant but I am struggling to find references for the case where $\kappa$ depends on $x$ and is not necessarily continuous.

Comment: Q1 makes no sense, weak formulations do not converge. Also there seems to be a sign error.

Comment: Q2 $H^1$ is the correct space

Comment: Q3 the system has the trivial solution $u=0$, which is bounded ofc. Otherwise you need some assumption on sign/size of $\kappa$ (think Lax-Milgram)

Comment: Thank you for your answers, @daw. I have slightly altered the first question. I have also placed an additional restriction on $\kappa$. Thanks for your input.